# To find integrating factor of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation of form

$$(4x^2 y + 5x^3 y^2 ) \, dx +(2x^3 + 3x^4 y) \, dy=0$$

I have tried everything but I do not know how they came up with $ xy $ as IF. Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: That isn't an equation

Comment: Is your expression equal to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $$\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(4x^2y+5x^3y^2)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x^3+3x^4y)}{y(2x^3+3x^4y)-x(4x^2y+5x^3y^2)}=\frac{1}{xy}$$ is a function of $xy$ only.

Thus $$e^{\int^{xy}\frac{1}{v}\,dv}=xy$$ is the IF for this DE.

**PS: Attached is an explanation if you are interested**

[image]

In case you are wondering what equation (1.2.1) is.

[image]

Comment: Which rule is this

Comment: Hi, I have edited my answer. You can look through the attached images to understand the reason.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a function $u(x,y)$ such that the following holds:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}N(x,y)-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}M(x,y)=u(x,y)\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\right)$$
where $M$ and $N$ are taken from the differential equation, $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$.

Replacing the appropriate expressions and dividing through by $u$ gives
$$\begin{align*}\frac{u_x}{u}(2x^3+3x^4y)-\frac{u_y}{u}(4x^2y+5x^3y^2)&=(4x^2+10x^3y)-(6x^2+12x^3y)\\
&=-2x^2-2x^3y
\end{align*}$$
You want $\dfrac{u_x}{u}$ and $\dfrac{u_y}{u}$ to be functions of $x$ and $y$, respectively; denote them as $F(x)$ and $G(y)$.
$$F(x)(2x^3+3x^4y)-G(y)(4x^2y+5x^3y^2)=-2x^2-2x^3y$$
Solving for $F(x)$, you have
$$F(x)=\frac{G(y)(4x^2y+5x^3y^2)-2x^2-2x^3y}{2x^3+3x^4y}$$
Notice that letting $G(y)=\dfrac{1}{y}$, you have
$$F(x)=\frac{4x^2+5x^3y-2x^2-2x^3y}{2x^3+3x^4y}=\frac{2x^2+3x^3y}{x(2x^2+3x^3y)}=\frac{1}{x}$$
This gives you the provided integrating factor,
$$\begin{align*}u(x,y)&=\exp\left(\int\frac{dx}{x}+\int\frac{dy}{y}\right)\\&=\exp\left(\ln x+\ln y\right)\\&=xy
\end{align*}$$